# Conan 1.x: How do I avoid passing on a default dependency option?

Tags: python, package, dependencies, conan

We are in the process of introducing conan into our build environment (for the time being we are stuck with 1.x, as things move slowly). It was new to me as well, so I'm still trying to find my footing.

Right now I'm facing the following problem (code represents snippets of the respective conanfile.py files):

I have a base package A with boolean option x, which defaults to false:

```
class A(ConanFile):
    name = "A"
    [...]
    options = {
        "x": [True, False]
    }
    default_options = {
        "x": False
    }
```

I have package B, which depends on A with option x=true to be built:

```
class B(ConanFile):
    name = "B"
    requires = [("A")]
    [...]
    default_options = {
        "A:x": True
    }
```

Important for later: the resulting libraries don't need option x to be true any more to be used.

Now I have packages C, D and E, which depend on A with option x=false, as well as B to be built:

```
class C/D/E(ConanFile):
    name = "C/D/E"
    requires = [("A"),
                ("B")]
    [...]
    default_options = {
        "A:x": False
    }
```

When I set the dependency of C to A and B *without* explicity setting option A:x to false as shown, it is set to true, even though its default is false. I guess that's because its overwritten by the dependency of B.

My question is, can I avoid always having to explicitly reset A:x to false, simply by telling B to *not* pass its option setting along? The thing is, every package which depends on B needs A:x to be false. As mentioned, once built it doesn't matter to B anymore if the option is set, but it matters to the other packages, but I'd like to avoid having to always think of setting the option when depending on package B as well, as this strikes me as an invitation for uneccessary errors, which sometimes can be quite hard to find (as I learned the hard way).

What I'd like is to tell B when being created as package to forget about this option, so it doesn't get passed along. However, simply resetting it in the package() method didn't work, and so far my research was fruitless, as every example regarding passing along options or inheritating them always only considered two levels, not three as in my case.

Any help would be apreciated!

Comment: Some important aspects if you are introducing Conan now: Use package names all in lowercase, not uppercase, as 2.0 forbids them.

Comment: I think you might want to omit the ``"A:x": True`` in the ``pkgB``, and provide it with CLI args like ``-o a*:x=True``, or with profiles. It is possible to protect against missing it with a ``validate()`` method. I think Github issues in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues is better for this kind of discussion and support

Comment: I usually use only lowercase, using uppercase here was just for clarification. But I didn't know 2.0 actually forbids them, so thanks for the information!
Your proposed idea regarding CLI or profiles conflicts with our approach to put all package related information into the conanfile.py, so we can use generalized package creation calls. I'll have to think about that.
I didn't turn to github first because I wasn't sure if it's actually an issue or if I'm simply lacking experience. But I'll give it a try.

Comment: This has been discussed in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/15309

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I learned when asking this question at https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues this is actually expected behaviour, I simply have a somewhat unusual setup of programs. The whole discussion (including a probably simpler solution for Conan 2) can be found [here](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/15309), but I'll post the answer to my question here anyway, so others can find it easier.

Basically, what I had to do is making sure the option is set only when needed. For this, inside package B, I moved it into the configure() method, as I can use conditionals there:

```
class B(ConanFile):
    name = "B"
    requires = [("A")]
    [...]
    options = {
        "libs_only": [True, False]
    }
    default_options = {
        "libs_only": False
    }

    def configure(self):
        if not self.options.libs_only:
            self.options["A"].x = True
```

And when I create the package to be used by other packages, I call

```
conan export-pkg . <user>/<channel> -f -pr=<profile> -o libs_only=True
```

I made use of the fact that I planned to differentiate the package anyway based on the content, as the resulting libs to be used by other packages are only part of the resulting artifacts. The others (only for which option "A.x" was important in the first place, but which are compiled simultanously, so the whole build is done with "libs_only=false") would be used in a different context, but there'd be package variants for them anyway.

(And yes, I'm somewhat contradicting myself with regard to my earlier comment, but the "libs_only" option is not uncommon in our case, so the generalized approach is still valid for us.)

So the solution for me basically was to find a fitting option for the package, which differs depending on if I'm building or packaging the package (in the latter case when aiming to be required by other packages as well), and set the troubling option accordingly in the configure() method.